# Flex 4 not sending POST data to php file

Tags: php, authentication, flex4

Trying to set up a simple login script in flex 4 with php.

**In flex I am using HTTPService:**

```
<s:HTTPService id="userRequest" result="checkLogin(event)" url="http://localhost/myPHPfile.php" useProxy="false" method="POST">`
    <mx:request xmlns=""> 
        <username>{username.text}</username> 
        <password>{password.text}</password> 
    </mx:request>
</s:HTTPService>
```

**A form to send the data:**

```
<mx:Form id="loginForm" backgroundColor="0x000000" color="0xFFFFFF">
    <mx:FormItem label="Username :">
        <s:TextInput id="username" color="#000000"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
    <mx:FormItem label="Password :">
        <s:TextInput displayAsPassword="true" id="password" color="#000000"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
    <mx:FormItem direction="horizontal">
        <s:Button label="Send" click="send_data()" color="white"/>  
        <s:Button label="Cancel" click="currentState = 'State1'" color="white"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
</mx:Form>
```

**And send script:**
    private function send_data():void { 
        userRequest.send(); 
    }

Pretty sure my PHP is OK, here is the code grabbing the POST data:

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
```

These vales in php ($username and $password) come back as blank values.  What is wrong with my FLex 4 script that is not sending the POST data appropriatley? Thanks!!!

Let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhhhh figured it out!

It actually WAS my mysql code.  Instead of

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
```

it needed to be

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
```

Removed the "i" at the end of mysql.  Weird how that works with php only script, but through Flex it doesnt. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <mx:request xmlns=""> 
            <username>{username.text}</username> 
            <password>{password.text}</password> 
        </mx:request>
```

username and password will be assigned on intializing. 
you must re set params.

change send scrtip as

```
private function send_data():void 
{ 
   var params:Object = {};
    params["username"] = username.text;
        params["password"] = password.text;
   userRequest.send(params); 


}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, what you say makes sense. However, even after inputing that into my send script, the result is the same. Any ideas why? (FYI, you put params["username'] twice, I fixed that.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
```

ok, work for me.